# How to mount UDF image WRITEABLE in Ubuntu 12.04 and later?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, mount

I finally upgraded my Ubuntu to v12.04 a couple of days ago. And it has given me a little problem. Suddenly I can no longer mount UDF images in a writeable state. That was no problem before upgrading.

```
mount -t udf -o loop,rw someImage.udf /tmp/cdr
```

That command would mount my UDF file into /tmp/cdr allowing me to add or remove files from the image, before unmounting again.

In Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.10 I can't do that. I get this warning:

```
mount: warning: content seems to be mounted read-only.
```

While browsing for answers I see that many people accept the answer that "ISO 9660 images are not supposed to be mounted in a writeable state".
That may be so, but UDF is not ISO9660. UDF is ISO13346, and it **is** supposed to be mountable in a writeable state.

See these links:

- http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/blu-ray-backup.htm
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17594/how-to-create-udf-images-and-burn-them-to-dvd-or-cdrom

In desperation I have tried the following:

- sudo chmod 777 on both the UDF image and the mounting point (before mounting)
- sudo chown myself.myself on the mounting point (after mounting)
- sudo mount -o remount,rw someImage.udf /tmp/cdr

But I'm not getting anywhere.
Hoping someone can help.

Comment: Exactly the same question.  No answer for four years. :(

Comment: try creating the udf image with `mkudffs --media-type=dvdrw`. see also https://github.com/pali/udftools/blob/master/doc/HOWTO.udf and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17594/how-to-create-udf-images-and-burn-them-to-dvd-or-cdrom and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152527/creating-a-pure-udf-iso